# How to configure react-app-rewired to add a postcss plugin

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, postcss, react-app-rewired

How can I customize [react-app-rewired](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-rewired) config in CRA v5 to add a postcss plugin, for example this [one](https://github.com/dmarchena/postcss-color-rgb)? I checked `react-app-rewired` documentation and github issues, but didn't find out how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the [react-app-rewire-postcss](https://github.com/csstools/react-app-rewire-postcss) library that does exactly what you need. There might be issues with PostCSS version, but you can definitely use the library's code as a hint about how what you need can be implemented.

Comment: the last update is 3 years old, but it works!